# Mandar el output de os.system() a una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un programa que usa un socket para mandar un string desde el cliente al servidor y ese string se guarda en una variable y pasa lo siguiente:

```
cmd = sock.recv(1024).decode()
os.system(cmd)
```

la cosa es que quiero mandar el output a el cliente, algo así:

```
output = os.system(cmd)
sock.send(output.encode())
```

No es necesario que sea con os.system() siempre y cuando pueda poner el output en una variable, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system()` no retorna ningun valor, por lo que si deseas obtener la respuesta del comando debes usar:

- `os.popen()`

  ```
  cmd = sock.recv(1024).decode()
  output = os.popen(cmd).read()
  sock.send(output.encode())
  ```
- `subprocess.Popen()`

  ```
  cmd = sock.recv(1024).decode()
  proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  (output, err) = proc.communicate()
  sock.send(output.encode())
  ```

Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3503909/6622587