# ¿Como capturar el string de los procesos que esta ejecutando el interprete de python en cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

No se si soy muy claro con la pregunta, basicamente quisiera saber si es posible capturar el string de los procesos que esta ejecutando python dentro de el cmd algo como lo siguiente:

Ejemplo:

Digamos que dentro de un script.py tnemos la siguiente linea `os.system('pip install google')` esta linea retornara una salida en la cmd.

algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puedo hacer para capturar ese texto que se muestra en la cmd y mostrarlo por ejemplo en una QLabel por ejemplo

Espero ser claro en la explicación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184072/mandar-el-output-de-os-system-a-una-variable/184074#184074) señalo porque no funciona `os.system()` y señalo alternativas. Pero en este caso propondre usar `QProcess` porque tiene la ventaja de que usa el event-loop de Qt evitando que se bloquee la GUI, en el siguiente ejemplo muestro la salida en un QTextEdit ya que se vera mejor que el QLabel.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.te = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.te.setReadOnly(True)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ejecutar comando")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        layout.addWidget(self.te)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardOutput)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.process.start("pip install google")

    def onReadyReadStandardOutput(self):
        self.te.append(self.process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Mientras que os.system() muestra la salida del comando en pantalla y
solamente retorna su código de error, os.popen() abre un pipe de
para lectura (por defecto) que permite leer la salida del proceso como si se
tratase de un archivo de python.

Un pequeño ejemplo sería:

```
import os
salida = os.popen('echo Hola').read()
print(salida) # Muestra 'Hola'
```